# .Net how to refresh token for DropBox?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dropbox

I making .Net MVC application that use DropBox as file storage.
I successfuly made uploading files to DropBox from my application but I get short time life token that expires evry 4 hour. I need some code examples how to refresh token.

```
 OAuth2Response CodeResponse = await DropboxOAuth2Helper.ProcessCodeFlowAsync(result.Data.Code, AppKey, AppSecret, RedirectUri);


                Settings.AccessToken = CodeResponse.AccessToken;
                Settings.RefreshToken = CodeResponse.RefreshToken;
```

Comment: Are you aware of/have you tried using the [refresh token API endpoint](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide#using-refresh-tokens)? If so, can you show your attempts/problems with it?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Can you please share this with code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can get long-term access by requesting "offline" access, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.

If you're using .NET, we recommend using [the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet). When you use the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK, you do not need to implement all of the code for the OAuth flow yourself. The SDK will do most of the work for you. You can find [examples of using this here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples).

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples how to make refresh token?

Comment: The links in my post above include example code for running the authorization process to get a refresh token, without or with the official Dropbox SDK.

Comment: I checked "examples of using this here" but I didn't find how to refresh token. Sorry.

Comment: That folder contains sample apps for this flow, such as [OAuthPKCE](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/OAuthPKCE) (meant for client-side apps) and [OauthBasic](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/main/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/OauthBasic) (meant for server-side apps).